# Multiple unexpected errors when compiling

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, linq-to-sql

I'm getting these weird compiler errors in my code:

```
} expected

Invalid token 'return' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Method must have a return type

Identifier expected

; expected

Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
```

All these errors are centered around the `GetTicketInfo` method.

This code was compiling and working just fine for days and now all of a sudden Visual Studio 2012 has a problem with it.

What am I doing wrong? Code is below.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace www.classes
{
  public class HelpDeskTicket
  {
    public int TicketId { get; set; }
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public String Category { get; set; }
    public String Requestor { get; set; }
    public String Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
    public long CategoryId { get; set; }
    public long StatusId { get; set; }
    public String TicketType { get; set; }
    public Guid RequestedBy { get; set; }
    public Guid AssignedTo { get; set; }
    public String AssignedToName { get; set; }
    public String ImpactAnalysis { get; set; }
    public String TestingRequirements { get; set; }
    public String ImpactOnSOP { get; set; }
    public String TrainingRequirements { get; set; }
    public String SourceVersion { get; set; }
    public int ReleaseNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime UATApprovalDate { get; set; }
    public String UATUserName { get; set; }
    public Guid? UATUserID { get; set; }
    public DateTime SecurityApprovalDate { get; set; }
    public Guid? SecurityOfficer { get; set; }
    public String SecurityUserName { get; set; }
    public DateTime PrivacyApprovalDate { get; set; }
    public Guid? PrivacyOffcer { get; set; }
    public String PrivacyUserName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CIOApprovalDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ITApprovalDate { get; set; }
    public String ITApproverName { get; set; }
    public Guid? ITApprovalBy { get; set; }
    public Guid? CIO { get; set; }
    public String CIOUserName { get; set; }
    public DateTime ProductionDate { get; set; }

    private static IQueryable<HelpDeskTicket> GetInfo(int ticketId, DbDataContext dc, DateTime _default)
    {
        return from ticket in dc.TicketLists
                       join category in dc.TicketCategories on ticket.CategoryID equals category.TicketCategoryID
                       join status in dc.StatusLists on ticket.StatusID equals status.StatusID
                       where ticket.TicketID == ticketId
                       select new HelpDeskTicket
                       {
                           TicketId = ticket.TicketID,
                           Title = ticket.Title,
                           Description = ticket.Description,
                           Category = category.CategoryName,
                           Requestor = GetRequestor(ticket.RequestedBy.Value, dc),
                           Status = status.Status,
                           CreatedOn = ticket.CreatedOn,
                           DueDate = ticket.DueDate.HasValue ? ticket.DueDate.Value : _default,
                           CategoryId = ticket.CategoryID.Value,
                           StatusId = ticket.StatusID.Value,
                           TicketType = ticket.TicketType,
                           RequestedBy = ticket.RequestedBy.Value,
                           AssignedTo = ticket.AssignedTo.Value,
                           AssignedToName = GetAssignee(ticket.AssignedTo.Value, dc),
                           ImpactAnalysis = ticket.ImpactAnalysis,
                           TestingRequirements = ticket.TestingReq,
                           ImpactOnSOP = ticket.ImpactOnSOP,
                           TrainingRequirements = ticket.TrainingReq,
                           SourceVersion = ticket.SourceVersion,
                           ReleaseNumber = ticket.ReleaseNumber.GetValueOrDefault(0),
                           UATUserID = ticket.UATUserid,
                           UATApprovalDate =
                               ticket.UATApprovalDate.HasValue ? ticket.UATApprovalDate.Value : _default,
                           UATUserName = GetTester(ticket.UATUserid.Value, dc),
                           SecurityOfficer = ticket.SecurityUserid,
                           SecurityUserName = GetSecurityOfficer(ticket.SecurityUserid.Value, dc),
                           SecurityApprovalDate =
                               ticket.SecurityApprovalDate.HasValue
                                   ? ticket.SecurityApprovalDate.Value
                                   : _default,
                           PrivacyOffcer = ticket.PrivacyUserid,
                           PrivacyUserName = GetPrivacyOfficer(ticket.PrivacyUserid.Value, dc),
                           PrivacyApprovalDate =
                               ticket.PrivacyApprovalDate.HasValue
                                   ? ticket.PrivacyApprovalDate.Value
                                   : _default,
                           CIO = ticket.CIOUserid,
                           CIOUserName = GetCIO(ticket.CIOUserid, dc),
                           CIOApprovalDate =
                               ticket.CIOApprovalDate.HasValue ? ticket.CIOApprovalDate.Value : _default,
                           ProductionDate =
                               ticket.ProductionDate.HasValue ? ticket.ProductionDate.Value : _default,
                           ITApproverName = GetITApprovalUser(ticket.ITUserId, dc),
                           ITApprovalDate = ticket.ITApprovalDate,
                           ITApprovalBy = ticket.ITUserId
                       };
    }

    public static HelpDeskTicket GetTicketInfo(int ticketId, DbDataContext dc)
    {
        private DateTime _default = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);

        return GetInfo(ticketId, dc, _default).SingleOrDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: A good thing to keep in mind is that if you have this under source control, you could look at previous version (a lot of source control software allows for file side-by-side comparison) and if this was compiling a few days ago just fine, then the private in there should show as a difference between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this is not the type of question StackOverflow tends to appreciate-- we've all been there with silly mistakes. This is a syntax issue.

Remove the `private` keyword from inside your method.

`private DateTime _default = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);`

to

`DateTime _default = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);`

Answer (score 4):

```
public static HelpDeskTicket GetTicketInfo(int ticketId, DbDataContext dc)
{
    private DateTime _default = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);

    return GetInfo(ticketId, dc, _default).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

I am positive that this code was not working couple of days ago, using access modifier `private` as you did is not legit, simply remove it.